# Req.user is available only under a specific route - NestJS

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I use NestJS with passport for my authentication via Google. Unfortunately, I have a problem with `req.user` as I can get it only under the callback route, but not anywhere else.

So the question is: **How to add req.user to all other routes within the module?**

To demonstrate it better: In my Google.strategy.ts I handle the req and all - and of course I have the access to the google's profile.

```
@Injectable()
export class GoogleStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'google') {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {
    super({
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY,
      callbackURL: '/api/v1/auth/google/callback',
      scope: ['email', 'profile'],
    });
  }

  async validate(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    const user = await this.authService.verifyUser(profile.id);

    if (user) {
      done(null, user);
      console.log('user already exists');
    } else {
      const user = this.authService.save({
        googleId: profile.id,
        displayName: profile.displayName,
      });
      done(null, user);
      console.log('user created');
    }
  }
}
```

Here lays the problem though, after the validation of the request I can access req.user ONLY in the callback route.

```
@Controller('/api/v1/auth/google/')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService, private readonly googleStrategy: GoogleStrategy) {
  }
  @Get('')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('google'))
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
  async googleAuth(@Req() req) {}

  @Get('callback')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('google'))
  async googleAuthRedirect(@Res() res, @Req() req) {
    //HERE IT WORKS AND I CAN ACCESS REQ.USER WITH ALL THE DETAILS
    console.log(req.user)

  }

  @Get('login')
  async info(@Req() req, @Res() res) {
   //HERE I GET 'UNDEFINED'
    console.log(req.user)
  }
}
```

I found this problem today when I was actually trying to grab the data from the callback route, but... I cannot!
I always get:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2...' (redirected from 'http://localhost:4000/api/v1/auth/google/callback') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I tried to enableCors, add options, headers... literally everything, but I'm still getting this error, so I wanted to use a different route with the req.user (and with plain express.js of course it worked). Any ideas, guys?

Comment: You don't use the guard on the `login` route, so `req.user` never gets populated by `passport` (which is what the `AuthGuard` uses under the hood). This is pretty expected

Comment: Fair enough, but if I put a guard there it will redirect me to the Oauth login section again. Does it use some sort of access token to check or idk? I use cookie parser to store my info.

Comment: So you send in a cookie, right? How do you verify the cookie has the right data? When do you call the `/login` endpoint?

Comment: Well, before I had my application written in expressJS, but there I wasn't using AuthGuards, so basically I had the access to the req.user on different routes, so I was just checking if the req.user !== null. But now, I struggle to get req.user on different endpoints and I would like to populate it on different guards for example.

Comment: Did you have a global middleware always calling  something like `passport.login()` or similar? Because that's the only way I could think of having `req.user` always as a property on the request

Comment: Hi, I`m being facing exact issue too. Did you find any solution?